# public void onSuccess(String result), from where/how the result is being set?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I've tried to follow the GWT RPC sample codes, and i don't understand how the AsyncCallback's Onsuccess method result is being set. Anyone help me to understand the flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
AsyncCallback<YourReturnType> callback = new AsyncCallback<YourReturnType>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(YourReturnType result) {
        //to do something with the result
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception ex) {
       //to do something with exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Kapelchik . My doubt is in onsuccess method (YourReturnType result). After the completion of Async call OnSucess's reult is being set. in turn the serviceImpl sets the result value. Here i don't understand how the serviceImpl gets called and set the value.
Thanks.

Comment: The return result is defined in a method of your class `ServiceImpl` and asynchronously transmitted to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajesh, I'm providing a [link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC#services) here. I hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks @RAS. i followed the same, and i got this question.
Thanks,